# Problem while booting the system

Tags: boot, encryption

While booting the system I end up with the following message on the screen:

```
1.264668) Integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 1.604188) ahci 0000:00:17.0: failed to start port 0 (errno=-12)
1.710942] xhcl_hcd 0000:00:14.0: can't setup: -12
1.711824] xhel hed 0000:00:14.0: init 0000:00:14.0 3.076265] 1915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] ERROR Scratch
fail, -12
setup failed
3.109239] 1915 0000:00:02.0: Device initialization failed (-12)
9.421994) ing 9: nobody cared (try booting with the "irapoll" option)
9.423012]
handlers: 9.423331] [<0000000007ef9518>] acpi_irg
9.423903] Disabling IRQ #9

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) exit
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems: -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: is /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I used `poweroff -f` command to shutdown. After that I used GRUB bootloader. There I used tlinux 5.13. It works properly.
[image: photo of screen showing initramfs prompt]

Comment: Hello. What system? Where are the details of what it is you are running or trying to do?

Comment: Booting Ubuntu OS.

Comment: I see `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root does not exist` which may indicate that your root file system is inaccessible. Can you describe the actions that led to the problem? Could the hard drive be disconnected, dead/dying, or perhaps you deleted the partition where Ubuntu was located?